# Puppet 5.3.3 and Powershell - returned 1 instead of one of [0]

Tags: powershell, puppet

Since moving to Puppet 5.3.3 I am experiencing puppet exit code 1 when running any powershell script that starts or invokes a process. As an example I have a powershell script that opens notepad:

```
Write-Host "Starting notepad ..."
[System.Diagnostics.Process] $proc = Start-Process -FilePath notepad -PassThru -Wait -ErrorAction stop
$EXIT_CODE=$proc.exitcode
Write-Host "notepad exit code is (${EXIT_CODE})"
```

Running this script directly in Powershell completes OK and returns expected results. When running via the following Puppet manifest I'm getting the error 'returned 1 instead of one of [0]'

```
Exec {
  provider  => powershell,
}

exec { 'test':
  command   => 'C:/build/test.ps1',
  timeout   => '0',
  logoutput => true,
}
```

This worked without issue on Puppet 4.x. It executes the first Write-Host and Start-Process functions but exits after the process completes. Full error below:

```
[Notice: /Stage[main]/Ingres::Win_installation/Exec[test]/returns: Starting notepad ...
[Notice: Applied catalog in 23.19 seconds
[Error: 'C:/build/test.ps1 notepad' returned 1 instead of one of [0]
[Error: /Stage[main]/Ingres::Win_installation/Exec[test]/returns: change from 'notrun' to ['0'] failed: 'C:/build/test.ps1 notepad' returned 1 instead of one of [0]
```

Any help appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

The guidance for the [Puppet PowerShell module in Github](https://github.com/puppetlabs/puppetlabs-powershell) calls this out actually. The suggested resolution is to always put an explicit `Exit` statement at the end of your PowerShell script to control the exit code:

> **External files and exit codes**
>
> If you are calling external files, such
>   as other PowerShell scripts or executables, be aware that the last
>   executed script's exitcode is used by Puppet to determine whether the
>   command was successful.
>
> For example, if the file C:\fail.ps1 contains the following PowerShell
>   script:
>
> `& cmd /c EXIT 5 & cmd /c EXIT 1` and we use the following Puppet
>   manifest:
>
> ```
> exec { 'test':
>   command   => '& C:\fail.ps1',
>   provider  => powershell,
> }
> ```
>
> Then the `exec['test']` resource will always fail, because
>   the last exit code from the external file C:\fail.ps1 is 1. This
>   behavior might have unintended consequences if you combine multiple
>   external files.
>
> To stop this behavior, ensure that you use explicit Exit statements in
>   your PowerShell scripts. For example, we changed the Puppet manifest
>   from the above to:
>
> ```
> exec { 'test':
>   command   => '& C:\fail.ps1; Exit 0',
>   provider  => powershell,
> }
> ```
>
> This will always succeed because the Exit 0 statement
>   overrides the exit code from the C:\fail.ps1 script.
>
> -- https://github.com/puppetlabs/puppetlabs-powershell#external-files-and-exit-codes

I'd suggest maybe doing this with a Try..Catch:

```
Try {
   .. your code ..
   Exit 0
} Catch {
   Write-Error $_
   Exit 1
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your feedback. I have changed the PowerShell script to use a Try..Catch, assigning Exit 0 to the Try and Exit 1 to the catch. I am getting the same result when running this via a Puppet manifest as shown in my original question. I'd rather avoid explicit exit statements as this will mask any issues with the script itself.

Comment: Yeah i'm trying to replicate and am seeing the same. It seems to be something to do with `start-process` as if you just call an .exe without that then you can after control the exit code with `exit` but seemingly when you use `start-process` adding `exit` is making not difference.

Comment: I have also tried it using Invoke-WmiMethod Win32_Process rather than start-process but with the same result. It's almost as if puppet believes the catalog has finished applying once these commands are run and ignores any subsesquent commands.

Comment: I haven't found any way to work around it other than to not use `start-process`.

Comment: I think the issue is in the timeout => 0.
I gave a look at the PowerShell's source code ( https://github.com/puppetlabs/puppetlabs-powershell/blob/7c8f2464dff5ce8bfd806fa900c8ff8985de5c50/lib/puppet/provider/exec/powershell.rb#L91 ).
If you pass 0, it actually waits 0 second then makes puppet fail.
If you remove the timeout parameter, the default is 300 seconds ( https://github.com/puppetlabs/puppetlabs-powershell/blob/master/lib/puppet_x/puppetlabs/powershell/powershell_manager.rb ).
: https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/bb355337(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: They used pipes, so I think the timeout is mandatory (not sure if this the same implementation they use): https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/bb355337(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Interesting! You should probably add that as an additional answer so it has greater visibility to future readers.

Answer (score 0):

I think the issue is in the timeout => 0. 
I gave a look at the PowerShell's source code: https://github.com/puppetlabs/puppetlabs-powershell/blob/7c8f2464dff5ce8bfd806fa900c8ff8985de5c50/lib/puppet/provider/exec/powershell.rb#L91

If you pass 0, it actually waits 0 second then makes puppet fail. If you remove the timeout parameter, the default is 300 seconds ( https://github.com/puppetlabs/puppetlabs-powershell/blob/master/lib/puppet_x/puppetlabs/powershell/powershell_manager.rb#L151 ).

Since they are using Pipes (haven't used them, so I may be wrong: https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/bb355337(v=vs.110).aspx ) the timeout is a required parameter, hence the only solution is to increase the timeout.